# Complicated jquery class selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this scenario:

```
element 1 [classList] = ['one', 'two']
element 2 [classList] = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

I want to remove class `two` from both the elements, when I click one of those(any) elements using this function

```
var target_element_class = e.target.className;
$('.'+target_element_class.replace(' ','.')).each(function(i, obj){
                $(this).removeClass('two');
            })
```

Now, this works fine when I click on element 1, since the query selector searches for `.one.two`, which is present in element 2.

But, when I click on element 2, it searches for `.one.two.three`, thus does not select element 1.

I want to be able to select element 1 also. Is there some way it is possible? More importantly, is this scenario valid?

**Edit** I have a script which is parsing an html doc. It could be any, so I don't have before hand knowldge of the element's classes. I click an element, it selects all other elements in the doc which has similar classes to it and adds class `two` to it. Then I should be able to click any of these selected elements so I can remove class `two` from all others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over each class on the clicked element that is not `two` and remove the class `two` from them like this:

```
var target_element_classes = e.target.classList;// array of all classes on clicked element
target_element_classes.forEach(function(c){
    if(c !== 'two'){
        $('.'+c).removeClass('two');
    } 
})
```